# Creating Category Specific menus

Tags: categories, menus

I have a question.. I am trying for this since many days.. but didn't get success. My requirement is say I have 5 categories: 
cat1,
cat2
cat3
cat4
cat5

Now each of category has 'N' number of posts.. What I want is on the Category page i.e. say I visited cat1 . So now archive page for Cat1 opens. I want to generate a dynamic menu now which has "All the Posts belonging to Cat1 hyperlinked." 
Live example say if you visit w3schools whenever you change category you see that category specific menu! Is it possible to do so? are there any plugins available? 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please post the code you've tried. What w3schools does is possible. They did it, right? It may be well beyond the scope of what can reasonably be answered on a site like thing though.

Comment: Are you looking for code or plugin? Not sure why you will need posts on the menu because on `archive.php` file  for cat1. All cat1 posts should be already showing on the page?

Comment: See..  I am not going to show all the posts belonging to a single category at a time when use basically enters that category page. What I am thinking is instead of that I show 10 posts and remaining you need not to always go back and next from links.. Instead you will be also shown those as hyperlinks menu.. Example you have 15 posts in total you will show all 15 hyperlinks in a menu I. E. Posts belonging to the category. I was thinking to write some custom code which finds category and gets all posts titles etc

Comment: See..  I am not going to show all the posts belonging to a single category at a time when use basically enters that category post. What I am thinking is instead of that I show 10 posts and remaining you need not to always go back and next from links.. Instead you will be also shown those as hyperlinks menu.. Example you have 15 posts in total you will show all 15 hyperlinks in a menu I. E. Posts belonging to the category. I was thinking to write some custom code which finds category and gets all posts titles etc